# Material UI change Input's active color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

How do I change the color of an active input? I'd like to change the default blue one but cant find how to.

From what I've tried it's not a matter of `color` attribute, neither in the FormControl, the InputLabel or the Input. Also there is no `underlineStyle` prop available ([docs](https://material-ui-next.com/api/input/))

I'd like to change the color only when the input is active, that is to say the user is writing in it, to my `primary` color as defined in my `theme`.

I'm using `Input` and not `TextField` because I want to use `InputAdornments` as per https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/#input-adornments.

**EDIT**

It seems like I should change `.MuiInput-inkbar-169:after`'s `background-color`. How do you suggest I do that? Is there another way?

```
/* eslint-disable flowtype/require-valid-file-annotation */

import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Input, { InputLabel } from 'material-ui/Input';
import { FormControl } from 'material-ui/Form';

const styles = theme => ({
    formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing.unit,
        width: '100%',
    },
    textField: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
        marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    }
});

class CustomInput extends React.Component {

    ...

    render() {
        const { classes, label, id } = this.props;
        const error = (this.props.valid === undefined ? false : !this.props.valid) && this.state.visited
        return (
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl} >
                <InputLabel error={error}>{label}</InputLabel>
                <Input
                    id={id}
                    className={classes.textField}
                    value={this.state.value || ''}
                    endAdornment={this.props.endAdornment ?
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                            {this.props.endAdornment}
                        </InputAdornment> : ''
                    }
                />
            </FormControl>
        );
    }
}

CustomInput.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomInput);
```

Adding this to my `style.css` does not change anything, even trying with an `!important`

```
.MuiInput-inkbar-169:after {
  background-color: #3f51b5 !important
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define some classes (pay attention to the *green* classes):

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  greenLabel: {
    color: '#0f0',
  },
  greenUnderline: {
    '&:hover:not($disabled):before': {
      backgroundColor: '#040',    
    },
  },
  greenInkbar: {
    '&:after': {
      backgroundColor: '#0f0',    
    },
  },
});
```

Add them as a `classes` prop using the [withStyles HoC](https://material-ui-next.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles):

```js
export default withStyles(styles)(ComposedTextField);
```

Override the classes used in the components with the classnames in the `classes` prop provided by withStyles:

```js
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel FormControlClasses={{ focused: classes.greenLabel }} htmlFor="name-simple">
            Name
          </InputLabel>
          <Input
            classes={{ inkbar: classes.greenInkbar, underline: classes.greenUnderline }}
            id="name-simple"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
```

[Input](https://material-ui-next.com/api/input/) uses the theme's primary color in its inkbar and underline classes, so we override them with the greenInkbar and greenUnderline classes we've defined.

For [InputLabel](https://material-ui-next.com/api/input-label/), which is a wrapper for [FormLabel](https://material-ui-next.com/api/form-label/), we have to pass classes through via the FormControlClasses prop.

Take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lyv2y3lk1q) for a working reproduction.

Comment: I actually have an issue with your answer: it works fine (thanks!) BUT I do have this warning in the console: `Warning: [JSS] Could not find the referenced rule disabled in CustomInput`. Any clue?

(If I comment out the new classes I added in the `style` object and comment out the `classes` attribute in the component, this error does not happen)

Comment: Sorry!  The use of $disabled in class rules requires a disabled class in the same sheet.  You need to override the disabled class as well.  Define a disabled class and override it just like you did with underline (by passing it to the component via classes).  Look at the original class in the Input, you can copy it: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Input/Input.js

Comment: @KenGregory the codesandbox example doesn't seem to be working any more